# Google Cast Media Player : Interpretation of url in smooth streaming manifest after redirect

Tags: media-player, chromecast, smooth-streaming

I'm using //developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/ version 0.5

I'm trying to use smoothstreaming on a chromecast device.

When fetching the manifest, the server does a redirect (http 302 with Location header)

E.g. from //example.com/one/manifest.ism/Manifest to //example.com/two/manifest.ism/Manifest

In the manifest coming from the second url a url attribute is present : Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(video={start time})

Apparently this url is interpreted by the player as relative to the original url (/one) instead of the redirected url (/two)

I had a look at the spec for smooth streaming manifest (//www.bogotobogo.com/VideoStreaming/Files/iis8/MS-SSTR.pdf) but it is not indicated how this url in the manifest should be interpreted.

I would expect it should be relative to the location of the url that was last fetched (relative to /two/) and not (relative to /one/)

Anyone knows whether this is an issue in the mediaplayer library (//developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/) from google or expected behaviour?

Thanks!